# How to build an Ionic application in Production mode, Ionic build is behaving differently

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

I am building my Ionic application for production. To do so, I am using `ionic build --prod` command and the application is building successfully, But when I am running my application on the server then it is giving me errors of:

`cordova.js`, `main.js`, `Vendor.js`.

[image]

(Please ignore the errors of Firebase)

The screenshot of network tab is:

[image]

As I am seeing my build folder, there are only two files that are generated after running the above ionic command i.e `Pollyfills.js` and 'sw-toolbox.js'.

But when I am using `Ionic serve` command then the build folder consists of all the files viz `Pollyfills.js`, `main.js`, `main.css`, `vendor.js` and 'sw-toolbox.js'.

I have already tried the various commands like :

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release` but it also results in only two files in Build folder and hence giving an error on console.

What is the issue and how can I make this app suitable for production mode.

Kindly have a look on my index.html file where I am giving the paths of various js files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>BOS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000">
<!--Share this Code -->
   <script src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5b1fb235e4b7fb00118c596f&product=sticky-share-buttons"></script>
  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href= "assets/imgs/logoSplash.png",>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="assets/imgs/logoSplash.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>


  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>

  <link rel="preload" href="build/main.css" as="style"
        onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>
<noscript>
  <h3 style="color: #673ab7; font-family: Helvetica; margin: 2rem;">
      Sorry, but app is not available without javascript
  </h3>
</noscript>
  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you building mobile app ?

Comment: Yes, I am building a hybrid application for Android and Iphone

Comment: Can you add that console error log so we can get idea whats going wrong ?

Comment: I have added an image of console error log, please have a look.

Comment: Open up the network tab and have a look at the response body for these scripts

Comment: In the response body, they are giving the index.html file. They will give the response like that because the `Build` folder under `www` folder is not generating the `vendor.js` and `main.js` files.

Comment: Can you see these files anywhere then?

Comment: No, I can't see these files.

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using? Did you see this ? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1782

Comment: I am using Ionic3. Yes, I have seen this, but I did not find any solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem. I went to the node_modules -> @ionic -> app-scripts -> config -> webpack.config

In that file, I had commented one line of code :

```
function getProdLoaders() {
  if (process.env.IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS === 'true') {
```

> // return optimizedProdLoaders; <= This one

```
  }
  return devConfig.module.loaders;
}
```

Now, it is working.

Comment: what if you use the command. `set IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS=false ionic build --prod` (windows), `IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS=false ionic build --prod` (mac, linux). this way a fresh npm i won't break your solution.